# How to structure related models in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, entity-relationship

I am having trouble figuring out how to handle a model with 'dynamic' related models.

There is a model named **Group**

When creating a group you can do a **GroupGame** or **GroupGamer**. This is specified by a group_type in the Group model. So type 1 would relate to GroupGame and 2 would be GroupGamer.

1. Am I supposed to do a polymorphic relationship here? And inverse the parent to GroupGame and GroupGamer which share a Group table? Or have Group the parent and it either has a related GroupGame or GroupGamer model.

I have other models like News, Media, etc. which I was planning to relate to Group model by using it's *id*.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/intradox/55cebe406a0e5c5c69cb

Just not sure how to go about this the right way.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, can you make it more clear with some code. What does `When creating a group you can do a GroupGame or GroupGamer` mean?

Comment: Here is a gist with some sample code/classes. Does it help? https://gist.github.com/intradox/55cebe406a0e5c5c69cb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the first part of your question polymorphic relations are the way to go. You create **Game** and **Gamer** model and they will both need to be "groupable" type of which will be determined by the "groupable_type" field. In the above case you use 3 tables - for **Gamer**, **Game** and the poly **Group** table.

```
//example table structure
    CREATE TABLE `group` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `groupable_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `groupable_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

//app/models/Group.php
class Group extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'group';

    public function groupable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}

//app/model/Gamer.php
class Gamer extends Eloquent
{
    ...

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Group', 'groupable');
    }

    ...
}

//app/model/Game.php
class Game extends Eloquent
{
    ...

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Group', 'groupable');
    }

    ...
}
```

As for the other models, that would be related to groups it's the same case - you can work the magic and also make them "groupable" which will enable you to just store all the group details in one table.

```
//app/model/News.php
class News extends Eloquent
{
    ...

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Group', 'groupable');
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I am confused about morphMany however. Each group will only have 1 game or 1 gamer. Basically it's a group but depending on the type will have additional attributes for a gamer or a game.  My understanding is a polymorphic would be good when you have a single game with multiple groups then you call a game and bring up all it's groups. But this is 1:1.

Comment: Check out this article for a typical example of basic polymorphism usage: http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/using-polymorphic-relationships-of-laravel-for-seo-content/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I split off into a separate question regarding grabbing data as I can't seem to pull my related model's data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487145/laravel-eager-loading-polymorphic-relationships