# Laravel Eager Loading Polymorphic Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eager-loading

Trying to eager load a model and it's related model but the related model returns null even though it has related data.

**Group Model is polymorphic 1:1 to either Game or Gamer.**

*Group Model Relationship:*

```
public function groupable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

*Game Model Relationship:*

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->morphOne('Group', 'groupable');
}
```

*Gamer Model Relationship:*

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->morphOne('Group', 'groupable');
}
```

*Query to Load Group then Game:*

```
$group = Group::whereSubdomain($id)->first();
$game = $group->game;
```

**Group returns the group but game returns null.**

*Here is a sample database entry for Groups table:*

```
id    subdomain    groupable_id    groupable_type
5     Starmade     10              Game
```

*Here is a sample database entry for Games table:*

```
id    genre    rating
10    7        4.5
```

Not sure where I am going wrong to have no game returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It might help.

```
    public function groupable()
{
    return $this->morphTo('groupable');
}
```

I had that problem too earlier, maybe you have the same prob like me. Essentially what I did was to help Laravel finds what columns it needs to look up for.