# Laravel 5.2 - Eager load distant model in Polymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel, model, polymorphism, eager-loading

I have a like system built with Polymorphic relations.
I'd like to eager load the model of the likeable_type when retrieving the Likes.
What do I need to do?
I tried to add

```
protected $with = ['Post'];
```

or

```
protected $with = ['App\Post'];
```

to my Like model but all I get is:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Post()

Like model:

```
class Like extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'likeables';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'likeable_id',
        'likeable_type',
    ];


    /**
     * Get all of the owning likeable models.
     */
    public function likeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [

        'picture',
        'description'

    ];


    /**
     *
     * a post belongs to one user
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }


    /**
     *
     * a post has many comments
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }


    /**
     * Get all of the post's likes.
     */
    public function likes()
    {        

        return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'likeable');
    }


    /**
     *
     * Simple Like System checks if liked
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsLikedAttribute()
    {
        $like = $this->likes()->whereUserId(Auth::id())->first();
        return (!is_null($like)) ? true : false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Show us your model.

Comment: I'll add to the question now.

Comment: Have you tried `protected $with = ['likeable']`? Usually when eager loading you refer to the relation by the method name

Comment: where? In the Like model?

Comment: Yes in the Like model, or `Like::query()->with('likeable')->get()`

Comment: it returns a null in relation: `#relations: array:1 [▼
        "likeable" => null
      ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133027/discussion-between-moak-and-chriz74).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eager Loading Polymorphic Relationships](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487145/laravel-eager-loading-polymorphic-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by renaming the table from 'likeables' to 'likes'.

`protected $table = 'likeables';` ->`protected $table = 'likes';`

Now I can retrieve the distant relation when retrieving the like like this:

```
$post = Post::find(6);

dd ($post->likes()->with('likeable')->get());
```

or I can retrieve the liked entity like this:

```
$like = Like::find(1);

$likeable = $like->likeable;

dd($likeable);
```

before renaming the table the result was Null..
I still have to understand how to retrieve all the entities liked by a User.