# Laravel polymorph one to one with custom columns

Tags: laravel

PayIn Model:
[PayIn Table](https://prnt.sc/13flob9)
**account_type** column will have either 10 or 11 as value which will help me identify the model I am morphing with .
**account_name** column will have the supplier/customer datas id.

```
   public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        Relation::morphMap([
            10 => Supplier::class,
            11 => Customer::class
        ]);
    }

 public function morphUserType()
    {
    
        return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'account_type', 'account_name');
    }
```

Supplier Model:

```
 public function payin()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(PayIn::class, 'morphUserType', 'account_type', 'account_name');
    }
```

Customer Model :

```
 public function payin()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(PayIn::class, 'morphUserType', 'account_type', 'account_name');
    }
```

Now the problem is .
when I do

> PayIn::with('morphUserType')->first();

it gives me 500 error .
but when I do

> $payin = PayIn::first(); $payin->morphUserType;

it gives me the output. The eager loading isnot working but lazy loading is . I cannot figure out why ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487145/laravel-eager-loading-polymorphic-relationships

Comment: sorry this is not helping ..  I think I have already done whats said in that answer .. it wont work

Comment: which version you are using

Comment: if it is greater than 5.8 version then see blog https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-8-22

Comment: laravel version 7.24 .. ok will have a look